# How to upload data frame from R to BigQuery to existing table?

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I have a dataframe which I have earlier uploaded to the GCP BQ table, but later on there was some mistake in the existing dataframe's column names and I changed the column names. I am doing the following in R to truncate the existing table and upload the new dataframe with changed column names.

```
 price_indices <- bq_table_create(x = stock_index_table, 
                                  fields = as_bq_fields(df), 
                                  overwrite = TRUE,
                                  friendly_name = "Price Indexes",
                                  description = "Price indexes for TCS stock"
                                        )
 bq_table_upload(x = stock_index_table, values = df,
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED', write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE')
```

When I run `bq_table_create` it gives me an error saying, table already exists. When I run `bq_table_upload` it gives me an error saying  `Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: No such field`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the table that exists has different columns than what you are trying to upload. Check the remote names and compare with what you have locally.

Comment: Yes, it has different column names.

Comment: I don't use that package, but can't you just either (a) change the local names to match the remote, or (b) drop the remote table and create it anew?

Answer (score 0):

Set the create_disposition parameter to "CREATE_NEVER" to avoid creating a new table, and set the write_disposition parameter to "WRITE_TRUNCATE" to overwrite the existing table.

```
 bq_table_upload(x = stock_index_table, values = df,
            create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER', write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE')
```